# iterate though unicode in vbs

Tags: unicode, vbscript

I need to convert accented letters to there regular counterparts i.e. À to A. I was planning of either just using a long list of replace statements like

```
orig_string = Replace(orig_string, "Ã", "a", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
```

or some sort of array to accomplish the same thing. I tried to paste into my access vb editor a list of characters áàâäãåǻăāąấấặắảạḁầẫẩậằẵẳ but got áàâäãå??????????????????. That being said I want to try using something along the lines of

```
Function convert_unicode(sIn As String) As String
    Dim r As New RegExp, a_patern As String
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection

    Debug.Print sIn

    **For a_patern = "\u00C0" To "\u00C5" <-pseudo code**
        With r
            .Pattern = a_patern
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = False
            convert_unicode = .Replace(sIn, "A")
        End With
    Next a_patern

   **For a_patern = "\u00C8" To "\u00CB"  <-pseudo code**
        With r
            .Pattern = a_patern
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = False
            convert_unicode = .Replace(sIn, "B")
        End With
    Next a_patern

    Debug.Print convet_unicode
End Function
```

Comment: if the file is in utf16 mode using your array should work.

Comment: You need to save your script file in Unicode format (in Notepad for instance you can select the encoding in the dropdown list at the bottom center of the *Save As* dialog). If your editor doesn't support Unicode: get an editor that does.

Comment: After compiling the list of characters I need to replace I realized for my purposes this type of loop wont work as each letter has accented versions scattered all over the Unicode chart so I will go back putting together array of Unicode. Ansgar thanks for coming up with an answer I'm sorry I'm not using it.

Comment: I not proficient enough in MS Access to know how to modify their IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A replacement loop could look somewhat like this:

```
s = "..."

For u = &h00c0 To &h00c5
  s = Replace(s, ChrW(u), "A")
Next
```

The `ChrW` function converts a character code to a (wide/Unicode) character.